# Django MPTT, recursively adding child node, giving wrong get_ancestors() results

Tags: django, recursion, mptt

I got the following code running recursively migrating data from an old table to MPTT

```
def traverse_design_idea(parent_id=1, parent=None):
    for _cat in OldTablefilter(parent=parent_id):
        cat = DesignCategory(name=_cat.category, old_id=_cat.sbt_id, parent=parent)
        cat.save()
        traverse_design_idea(_cat.sbt_id, cat)   
traverse_design_idea()

cat = DesignCategory.objects.get(pk=100)
cat.get_ancestors() //give wrong parents
```

The relationships are set correctly but get_ancestors() give wrong information, I have read about updating the parent nodes but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just figured out I can simply run `DesignCategory.objects.rebuild()` after the recursive function